# jquery ui dialog disables input text and textarea

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have an html page which has some html form elements and jquery

if I open the html page as a standalone page, everything seems fine, however, if I open the page as jquery ui dialog whithin an aspx web forms page (I get the contents of the html page through jquery ajax method), the input elements text and textarea are not enabled, but select lists are enabled.

The problem is coused by modal property.

If the modal is false, then the fields are editable

Any ideas why this happens this?

Comment: Posting your code and a jsFiddle would be quite helpful.